# MySQL: Applying SQL Script to Database, Error 1826

Tags: mysql, sql, database, model

Before we start, here is my sql database model for reference.

[image: MySQL E/RModel]

Here is what my plan was: `ProductType` can have many `Shipment Order`, but Shipment Order can only have one ProductType. When I try and create a relationship, I had gotten this:

[image: Error 1826]

I had read other threads about this, but I honestly do not know how to apply it to my case, nor the proper way for it to get it fixed.

Comment: You already have a constraint named `ProductType_Base_ID` somewhere in your database, maybe in another table.

Comment: @Barmar I believe I had already connected ProductType_Base_ID with FK_ProductType_Inventory_ID.

Comment: Then why are you trying to add it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already a table that has a constraint named `ProductType_Base_ID`. You can find the table with the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ProductType_Base_ID';
```

But you don't really need to find it, just use a different name for this foreign key constraint.